# How to read Slave name in JMeter script

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can we read Slave name in JMeter script or plugin?

I need to execute a sample in specific slave.

I am using Docker based master and slave setup : https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how

Answer (score 0):

Put this sampler under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function as the condition

Something like:

```
 ${__jexl3("${__machineName()}"=="hostname of your slave",)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support. Really appreciate your help.